# サブプロセスのbashにエスケープシーケンスを送信したい

Tags: python, linux, bash

サブプロセスとして起動したbashに、カーソル↑キーを送信したいと思っています。

そのために、以下の実験コードを書きました。

```py
import os

p = os.popen('bash -i', 'w')
p.write('echo test\n')
p.write('\x1b[A\n')
p.write('exit\n')
p.close()
```

結果として、ターミナルエミュレータから実行した場合と、
テキストエディタから実行した場合で挙動がことなります。
これはどのような仕組みでこうなるのでしょうか。
何卒ご教示ください。

ターミナルエミュレータから実行した場合は、想定通りの動作をします。

```
$ python test.py
user@ubuntu18:~$ echo test   <- bashが起動して"echo test" が実行される
test
user@ubuntu18:~$ echo test   <- カーソル↑により"echo test" がまた実行される
test
user@ubuntu18:~$ exit        <- bashが終了する
exit
$
```

テキストエディタ(emacs)から実行した場合は、エスケープシーケンスが認識されません。

```
test
bash: line 2: $'\E[A': command not found
```

環境はUbuntu18.04です。

Comment: Emacs からどのように test.py を実行したのでしょう？Python mode で 'C-c C-c' してもEmacs 内にターミナルを立ち上げて '$ python test.py' を実行しても user28998 さんがターミナルエミュレータからじっこうした結果と同様になりました。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。 `M-x shell` からコマンド実行しています。こちらはpython-modeの `C-c C-c` が効かないのですが、lispで `(shell-command)` とするとおっしゃるとおり想定どおりに動きました。

Comment: エスケープシーケンスが認識されていない様なので、emacs のシェルで `export TERM=vt100` を実行してみるとよいかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！おっしゃるとおりでした！！！ `export TERM=vt100` でかいけつしました！！！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(コメントより)

エスケープシーケンスが認識されていない様なので、emacs のシェルで `export TERM=vt100` を実行してみるとよいかもしれません。